# Como fazer um filtro usando LIKE em campos do tipo int em um DataView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Estou usando o código abaixo para fazer um filtro em meu `DataGridView`, porém quando faço o filtro utilizando o *like* em um campo do tipo `int`, recebo o seguinte erro:

> Não é possível realizar a operação 'Like' em System.Int32 e System.String.

Segue o código:

```
Private Sub txtProcura_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtProcura.TextChanged
    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Try
        Select Case cboxFiltro.SelectedItem
            Case Is = "Pedidos"
                dv = New DataView(dt, "Pedido like '%" & txtProcura.Text & "%'", "Pedido asc", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows)
            Case Is = "Chave"
                dv = New DataView(dt, "chave like '%" & txtProcura.Text & "%'", "Pedido asc", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows)
        End Select

        dgvPedidosSAT.DataSource = dv
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Alguém teria uma solução?

Comment: `dt` é um `DataTable`?

Comment: Isso mesmo, Mateus!

Comment: Não necessariamente, posso variar, mas estou usando isso pq fiz uma query e funcionou perfeitamente, só não entendi pq nao funcionou com o DataView.
Qual é a sua sugestão ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso você precisa converter sua coluna para `String`, fazendo assim:

```
dv = New DataView(dt, "CONVERT(Pedido, 'System.String') like '%" & txtProcura.Text & "%'",
                    "Pedido asc", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows)
```

Outra maneira de fazer o que você quer é através do próprio `DataTable`, assim:

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CONVERT(Pedido, 'System.String') like '%" & txtProcura.Text & "%'"
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Pedido asc"
```

Um detalhe importante sobre o *like* é que os caracteres `*` ou `%` não podem ser utilizados no meio da sua expressão, por exemplo:

```
'%123' - válido
'123%' - válido
'%12%' - válido
'1%34' - inválido
```

Você pode dar uma olhada [nesse link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) para saber mais sobre as expressões aceitas.

Comment: Funcionou Mateus!
Muito Obrigado, mesmo!